# Unable to verify with fingerprint sensor

Tags: login, thinkpad

I want to enable the fingerprint sensor on my laptop and I want to log in with this stuff. After I have installed `fingerprint-gui` `fprint_demo`, they all scanned my finger for five times, but when I try to verify with same finger, I always got "not match" or "verify failed", only a few times was recognized. Do you have any experience on using a fingerprint reader? any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Some finger scanners are unreliable. And some fingers are not good. E.g my fingers are detected well, but my wife's is detected from time to time. I do not think anything can be done.

Comment: @Pilot6 how you scan your finger with this device? Parallel with the laptop keyboard face? Or any angle?

Comment: I try to do it from up to down straight. But other ways do not help. Now I do not use it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did it as well as you said, but it never works. Maybe it is caused by hardware or software issue, take some security problems (it remains on keyboard or anywhere else) into consideration, I choose to leave it there. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.